# bootstrap custom navbar with lines

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create this `navbar` in `bootstrap 4`:

But I really don't know how :/, could anybody give any advice?! Take a look at those lines at the left and right of the `navbar` and behind the image in center, those lines are what I want in this case, and I need the image be in the center and the other links right and left of it.

Any respond is welcome ♥.

Comment: did you tried something so far?

Comment: @Kristianmitk yes i tried to do it at the custom way but didn't worked very well, and before that i tried using bootstrap but the problem was i didn't know how to center the image and other links in left and right of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give you an idea, you can use a strike class like below to draw a line on either side of the text...

```css
/* strike: text inside a line */
.strike {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.strike > span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.strike > span:before,
.strike > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #d8d8d8;
}

.strike > span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.strike > span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="strike">
        <span>some text1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="strike">
        <span>some text2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="strike">
        <span>some text3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer... to show how to put 3 texts with strike, side by side

Comment: can you help me with this: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e6bo64ef/5/) i don't know why the line doesn't show up using bootstrap?!

Comment: I noticed you had a typo... striker instead of strike... beyond that, could please post a new question as I am not really clear about the expected output.

Comment: take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6bo64ef/11/) in collapsed navbar it shows the lines but when the navbar is expanded lines won't show up